# Как вытянуть элементы из списков

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Пишу парсер в котором мне нужно вытянуть информацию о диагонали и разрешении телевизоров, получил вот такие вот списки

```
['', 'Діагональ:', '43" (109 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Bluetooth, ', 'Wi-Fi', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '32" (81 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '1366 х 768 (WXGA)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Wi-Fi', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '43" (109 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Bluetooth, ', 'Wi-Fi', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '50" (127 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Wi-Fi, ', 'Bluetooth', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '32" (81 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '1920 х 1080 (Full HD)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'DLNA, ', 'Wi-Fi, ', 'Wi-Fi Direct', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '40" (101 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '1920 х 1080 (Full HD)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Wi-Fi, ', 'Bluetooth', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '43" (109 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '1920 х 1080 (Full HD)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Bluetooth, ', 'Wi-Fi', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '24" (60 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '1366 х 768 (WXGA)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Wi-Fi, ', 'Bluetooth', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '50" (127 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Bluetooth, ', 'Wi-Fi', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '32" (81 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '1366 х 768 (WXGA)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Bluetooth, ', 'Wi-Fi', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '32" (81 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '1920 х 1080 (Full HD)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Wi-Fi, ', 'Bluetooth', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '43" (109 см)', '']
['', 'Роздільна здатність:', '3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)', '']
['', 'Формат екрану:', 'широкоекранний (16:9)', '']
['', 'Тип підсвітки:', 'LED', '']
['', 'Бездротові комунікації:', 'Bluetooth, ', 'Wi-Fi, ', 'Miracast, ', 'Wi-Fi Direct', '']
['', 'Діагональ:', '55" (140 см)', '']
```

В вот таком вот html коде

```html
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">43" (109 см)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Роздільна здатність:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Формат екрану:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">широкоекранний (16:9)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Тип підсвітки:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">LED</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Бездротові комунікації:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="white-space: pre-line">Bluetooth,
Wi-Fi</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">32" (81 см)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Роздільна здатність:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">1366 х 768 (WXGA)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Формат екрану:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">широкоекранний (16:9)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Тип підсвітки:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">LED</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Бездротові комунікації:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="white-space: pre-line">Wi-Fi</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">43" (109 см)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Роздільна здатність:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Формат екрану:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">широкоекранний (16:9)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Тип підсвітки:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">LED</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Бездротові комунікації:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="white-space: pre-line">Bluetooth,
Wi-Fi</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">50" (127 см)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Роздільна здатність:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Формат екрану:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">широкоекранний (16:9)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Тип підсвітки:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">LED</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Бездротові комунікації:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="white-space: pre-line">Wi-Fi,
Bluetooth</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">32" (81 см)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Роздільна здатність:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">1920 х 1080 (Full HD)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Формат екрану:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">широкоекранний (16:9)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Тип підсвітки:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">LED</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Бездротові комунікації:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="white-space: pre-line">DLNA,
Wi-Fi,
Wi-Fi Direct</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">40" (101 см)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Роздільна здатність:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">1920 х 1080 (Full HD)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Формат екрану:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">широкоекранний (16:9)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Тип підсвітки:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">LED</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Бездротові комунікації:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="white-space: pre-line">Wi-Fi,
Bluetooth</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">43" (109 см)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Роздільна здатність:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">1920 х 1080 (Full HD)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Формат екрану:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">широкоекранний (16:9)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Тип підсвітки:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">LED</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Бездротові комунікації:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="white-space: pre-line">Bluetooth,
Wi-Fi</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">24" (60 см)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Роздільна здатність:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">1366 х 768 (WXGA)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Формат екрану:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">широкоекранний (16:9)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Тип підсвітки:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">LED</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Бездротові комунікації:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="white-space: pre-line">Wi-Fi,
Bluetooth</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">50" (127 см)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Роздільна здатність:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Формат екрану:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">широкоекранний (16:9)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Тип підсвітки:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">LED</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Бездротові комунікації:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="white-space: pre-line">Bluetooth,
Wi-Fi</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prop-item">
<td class="prop-item-title">Діагональ:</td>
<td class="prop-item-value" style="">32" (81 см)</td>
</tr>
```

Как отсюда с помощью bs4 мне вытянуть диагональ и разрешение телевизора?

Вот мой пайтон код

```
def parse(url):
    item_list = []
    items_dig = []
    req = requests.get(url)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    items = soup.find_all(class_="listing__body-wrap image-switch")
    for footer in items:
        foot = footer.find_all(class_="card__footer")
        for foot_info in foot:
            foot_info_div = foot_info.find_all(class_="prop-main")
            for footer in foot_info_div:
                footer_value = footer.find_all("tr", class_="prop-item")
                for footer_final in footer_value:
                    footer_changer = footer_final
                    print(footer_changer)
```

Comment: Достаточно одной таблетки find_all("tr", class_="prop-item").

Comment: Так у меня написано это, и выводит не только первые 2 блока tr которые мне нужны, а все, как это можно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
footer_value = soup.find_all('tr')
for footer in footer_value:
    if footer.find('td', class_='prop-item-title').text == 'Діагональ:':
        aa = footer.find('td', class_='prop-item-value').text
        print(f'Діагональ: {aa}')
    if footer.find('td', class_='prop-item-title').text == 'Роздільна здатність:':
        at = footer.find('td', class_='prop-item-value').text
        print(f'Роздільна здатність: {at}')

Діагональ: 43" (109 см)
Роздільна здатність: 3840 x 2160 (4K UHD)
Діагональ: 32" (81 см)
Роздільна здатність: 1366 х 768 (WXGA)
....
```